# Is there a way to enable c++11 support for catkin packages?

Tags: catkin, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to use auto and lambda functions, but it isn't working by default.

And I wasn't able to find how to set compiler option -std=c++11.

Is there a way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152276/is-there-a-way-to-enable-c++11-support-for-catkin-packages?/) by [INait](https://answers.ros.org/users/11781/inait/) on ROS Answers with karma: 220 on 2014-04-12

Post score: 19

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2014-04-14**:
This is a very bad idea to use C++11 in ROS linked modules. There is no guarantee that C++03 and C++11 will stay ABI-compatible! It may break at anytime without prior notice because it only works ""by chance"" currently! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637699/c03-library-with-c11-source-code

**Comment by [jespestana](https://answers.ros.org/users/4328/jespestana/) on 2014-09-25**:
I have had problems with C++11 and ROS in the past. If you have a robot with Ubuntu 12.04 preinstalled you are going to have a bad time using C++11, because the boost version in 12.04 is not compatible with C++11. I recommend using C++03 which is the standard: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should just be able to set the -std=c++11 flag in CMakeLists.txt of the package:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

If you want to enable it only when possible, I use this to do so:

```
# check c++11 / c++0x
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()
```

If you don't want to stop when 11 or 0x is not detected, simply comment out those lines.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2014-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 26

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-04-12**:
This is cool for local/experimental development, but do note that the catkin CMake style guide forbids altering CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, cf. http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/user_guide/standards.html .

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-04-12**:
The target platform for Hydro and Indigo is C++03, as noted here: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html .

**Comment by [INait](https://answers.ros.org/users/11781/inait/) on 2014-04-12**:
Great, thanks!

**Comment by [vik748](https://answers.ros.org/users/29926/vik748/) on 2017-07-10**:
Is there a way to add this flag for an individual file and not the entire project?